# Where is the Black Market Auction House?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Mists of Pandaria, Blizzard have added a Black Market Auction House to the game, in order to purchase items that are otherwise hard to get or no longer available by normal methods in game.

Where in the game world is the Black Market Auction House located, is it faction specific, and are there any requirements in order to be able to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken [from WoWJuju](http://www.wowjuju.com/_/wowarticles/black-market-auction-house-all-you-need-to-know-r201):

> You'll need the MoP expansion.
> The Veiled Stair is a level 87 area.
>
> The BMAH is located within the Veiled Stair area, a northern subregion of the Valley of the Four Winds. A bit to the south-east of the Tavern the Mists you will be able to find Madam Goya, who is the leader of the BMAH.
>
> You need a lot of gold, as the lowest bids start at 10k.
> The area is not a safe zone, so you can expect a lot of ganking on PvP realms.

[image: map location]

For more information about the BMAH (Black Market Auction House) click on my link above, [or here](http://www.wowjuju.com/_/wowarticles/black-market-auction-house-all-you-need-to-know-r201).

Comment: Oh, the Veiled Stair? Isn't that the same area you find The Black Prince, to hand in the Mysterious Note quest to start the legendary questline?

Comment: @pixel I believe your correct. I haven't done that quest since the Beta though, so don't quote me on it. ;)

Comment: Confirmation; [Wrathion resides now in the Tavern in the Mists, which is found in the Veiled Stair of Pandaria](http://www.wowpedia.org/Wrathion).

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.wowhead.com/news=204376/mists-of-pandaria-black-market-auction-house, the Black Market Auction House is run by [Madam Goya](http://mop.wowhead.com/npc=62943) in [The Veiled Stair](http://mop.wowhead.com/zone=6006) in Pandaria.

It is not faction-specific, so as to encourage lots of bidding on all the items. For this reason it's unknown if faction-specific mounts will ever appear there.